# Implementing validation rules inside of class

Tags: c#, reflection, validationrules

I have `class` like this

```
public class EmployeeInfo
{
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Office { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
}
```

I've created method that takes `SPListItemCollection` as parameter and returns list of object of `EmployeeInfo` class.There is no restrictions inside `SPList` and when you create new item you can leave some of the fields empty, so I've used `reflection` to determine if field is `null` and then insert empty string when populating `EmployeeInfo`object to avoid exceptions.

```
 public List<Models.EmployeeInfo> GetEmployeeInfo(SPListItemCollection splic)
 {

        var listEmployeeInfo = new List<Models.EmployeeInfo>();
        var propertyNames = new List<string>() { "EmployeeName", 
                                                 "Department", 
                                                 "Office", 
                                                 "PhoneNumber"};

        foreach (SPListItem item in splic)
        {
            var employeeInfo = new Models.EmployeeInfo();


            foreach (var propertyName in propertyNames)
            {
                string newData = "";
                if (item[propertyName] != null)
                {
                    newData = item[propertyName].ToString();
                }

                employeeInfo.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(employeeInfo, newData, null);


            }
            listEmployeeInfo.Add(employeeInfo);
        }

        return listEmployeeInfo;

    }
```

Later I've learned that it is bad practice to use `reflection` inside of nested loops , so I'm looking for different approach.
Is there any chance I can make some pre Validation Rules inside `EmpployeeInfo` class , something like Validation method or to write some code inside class properties and than inside of `GetEmployeeInfo` method just to populate properties by calling that method?
Thank you.

Comment: by Validation Rules, do you mean the properties value have to be limited to certain values? You can certainly do that by writing something in `get {} and set{}`

Answer (score 1):

just write c'tor:

```
public EmployeeInfo(string employeeName ,string phoneNumber, string office, string department)
{
    EmployeeName  = employeeName;
    PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    Office = office;
    Department = department;
}
```

and you can call it like this:

```
var employeeInfo = new Models.EmployeeInfo(item["EmployeeName"] ?? "", item["PhoneNumber"] ?? "", item["Office"] ?? "", item["Department"] ?? "");
```

anyway, you should avoid declaring fields as public, as it breaks encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add the logic in the seperate getters and setters

```
    public class EmployeeInfo
    {
        private string employeeName;
        public string EmployeeName 
        {
           get
           {
                return employeeName ?? ""; //Returns the content, or an empty string if it is null
           } 
           set
           {
                 employeeName = value;
           }
       }


    }
```

This way you get a standard value (say `""`) instead of null when accessing the property.